# How to modify the gradle task openapi3's dependsOn. The gradle plugin is written in kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin, spring-restdocs

I added a gradle plugin `com.epages:restdocs-api-spec-gradle-plugin:0.9.0` which exposes a gradle task `openapi3`. This task `dependsOn` `check` task which run all my tests. I'd like to have this task depends on `myCustomTest` task which only run a subset of my tests. How would I go about doing that?

So far I can't seem to even add a `dependsOn` to it, even though adding `dependsOn` might not be the solution. I got the following error:

```
Could not find method dependsOn() for arguments [task ':myCustomTest'] on object of type com.epages.restdocs.apispec.gradle.OpenApi3Extension
```

when I try to do any of the following:

- `openapi3.dependsOn myCustomTest`
- `openapi3 { dependsOn myCustomTest }`

One thing special about this plugin is that it is written in kotlin, here is the source: https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-api-spec/tree/master/restdocs-api-spec-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple solution to my own question above. It turns out I can just run openapi3 with -x to skip certain tasks. So something like the following would work the way I wanted:

```
gradle myCustomTest openapi3 -x check
```

No need to modify gradle build script.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that openapi3 is registered as an Extension and after evaluate the task is registered with the same name, you cannot statically declare it, thus use the dynamic mode:

```
 myCustomTest.finalizedBy {
       tasks.findAll {task -> task.name.startsWith('openapi3')}
 }
```